# Creating an employee for each user record

Tags: django

I want to create a record in employee model each time I create an user. Any suggestions about how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the Django-supplied User model, then probably best to use pre-save or post-save [signals.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/signals/)

If you mean your own model, [you can subclass its save method.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods)